# Rails API GraphQL server on Heroku not working

Tags: heroku, graphiql

I've developed a Rails API backend that is set up with Graphql.  When I'm running the server locally, I can make successful queries at http://localhost:3000/graphiql, but now that my app is deployed on Heroku, I cannot access my Graphiql on www.mysite.heroku.com/graphiql.  Should I be able to?  I'm now developing a React front end with Appolo trying to make queries to this API, and I can't seem to get it to work.  I wonder if there is some kind of Heroku configuration I'm missing for Graphiql, and curious if the fact that I can't access www.mysite.heroku.com/graphiql is a dead giveaway that something is not working.  Appreciate any incite.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your routes file? Does it look like this?

```
  if Rails.env.development?
    mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
  end
```

If you want to access it you should remove the conditional or add and env like staging or production like:

```
  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.staging?
    mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
  end
```